# Tesseract OCR - Handwritten font

Tags: ocr, tesseract, handwriting

I'm trying to use [Tesseract-OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) to detect the text of images with pure text in it but these text has a handwritten font called **Journal**.

Example:

[image]

The result is not the best:

> Maxima! size` W (35)

Is there any possibility to improve the result or rather to get the exact result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like Andrew Cash mentioned, it'll be very hard to perform OCR for that T letter because of its intersection with a number of next characters.

For results improvement you may want to try a more accurate SDK. Have a look at [ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK](http://www.ocrsdk.com/), it's a cloud-based OCR SDK recently launched by ABBYY. It's in beta, so for now it's totally free to use. I work @ ABBYY and can provide you additional info on our products if necessary. I've sent the image you've attached to our SDK and got this response:

```
Maximal size: lall (35)
```

Comment: To be fair, the question title mentions Tesseract implying he was asking how to perform this *with Tesseract*.

Answer (score 5):

I am surprised Tesseract is doing so well.  With a little bit of training you should be able to train the lower case 'l' to be recognised correctly.

The main problem you have is the top of the large T character.  The horizontal line extends across 2 (possibly 3) other character cells and this would cause a problem for any OCR engine when it tries to segment the characters for recognition.  Training may be able to help in this case.

The next problem is the . and : which are very light/thin and are possibly being removed with image pre-processing before the OCR even starts.

Overall the only chance to improve the results with Tesseract would be to investigate training.  Here are some links which may help.

[Alternative to Tesseract OCR Training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509723/alternative-to-tesseract-ocr-training)
[Tesseract OCR Library learning font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908919/tesseract-ocr-library-learning-font)
[Tesseract confuses two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292991/tesseract-confuses-two-numbers)